# ORM query? or updated DB table information should updated into hibernete web application?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, database-design, orm

**The problem statement :**
Example : I have table name called "STUDENT" and it has 10 rows and consider one of the rows has name as "Jack". So when my server started and running I make the DB database into cache memory so my application has the value of "jack" and I am using it all over my application.

Now external source changed my "STUDENT" table and changed name "Jack" into "Prabhu Jack". I want the updated information asap into my application with out reloading/refresh into my application.. I dont want to run some constant thread to monitor and update my application. All I want is part of hibernate or any feasible solution to achieve this?

..

Comment: This is too general. Please read about [mcve]s.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is the classic case of whether to *pull* or *push* updates.

**Pull**

This approach relies on the application using some background thread or task system that periodically polls a resource and requests the desired information.  Its the responsibility of the application to perform this task.

In order to use a *pull* mechanism in conjunction with a cache implementation with Hibernate, this would mean that you'd want your Hibernate query results to be stored in a L2 cache implementation, such as ehcache.

Your ehcache would specify the storage capacity and expiration details and you simply query for the student data at each point you require it.  The L2 cache would be consulted first, which lives on the application server side, and would only consult the database if the L2 cache had expired.

The downside is you would need to specify a reasonable time-to-live setting for the L2 cache so that the cache got updated by a query within reason after the rows were updated.  Depending on the frequency of change and usage, maybe  a 5 minute window is sufficient.

Using the L2 cache prevents the need for a useless background poll thread and allows you to specify a reasonable poll time all within the Hibernate framework backed by a cache implementation.

**Push**

This approach relies on the point where a change occurs to be capable of notifying interested parties that something changed and allowing the interested party to perform some action.

In order to use a *push* mechanism, your application would need to expose a way to be told a change occurred and preferably what the change actually was.  Then when your external source modifies the table in question, that operation would need to raise an event and notify interested parties.

One way to architect this would be to use a JMS broker and have the external source submit a JMS message to a queue and have your application subscribe to the JMS queue to read the message when its sent.

Another solution would be to couple the place where the external source manipulates the data tightly with your application such that the external source doesn't just manipulate the data in question, but also sends a JSON request to your application, allowing it to update its internal cache immediately.

**Conclusion**

Using a *push* situation could require the introduction of additional middleware components, should you want to efficiently decouple the external source side & your application.  But it does come with the added benefit that the eventual consistency between the database and your application's cache should happen with relative real-time.  This solution also has no additional needs for querying the database after startup for those rows.

Using a *pull* situation doesn't require anything more than what you're likely already using in your application, other than maybe using a supported L2 cache provider rather than some homegrown solution.  However, the eventual consistency between the database and your application's cache is completely dependent on your TTL configuration for that entity's cache.  But be aware that this solution will continue to query the database to refresh the cache once your TTL has expired.